# System.InvalidCastException: 'Operator '+' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Integer'.'

Tags: database, vb.net, odbc

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and generating .NET Framework 4.7.2 with VB.NET Windows Forms.

The problem is when I follow the tutorial video from my teacher. When the program connects to the database, my program is running but when I hit the save button this message shows up:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Operator '+' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Integer'.'

Here is the code :

```vb
If rd.HasRows Then
    Dim ubah As String

    ubah = "Update from cabang set total ='" & rd.Item("total") + 1 &
        "' where id='" & Mid(ComboBox1.Text, 1, 1) & "'"
    cmd = New OdbcCommand(ubah, conn)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End If
```

Comment: Do not slam the code and expect us to understand it ,**Explain** the problem and what you're trying to do so we can help you

Comment: I can explain just like that, sorry. because i just learn this program @Makdous

Answer (score 0):

There are assumptions around the `rd.Item("total") + 1` expression, assumptions that your data is breaking: if `rd.Item("total")` yields `DBNull`, you can't legally perform that `+ 1` operation - hence the `InvalidCastException`.

Consider separating the "get the value from `rd.Item("total")`" part from the "add `1` to the value of `rd.Item("total")`" part, and verifying if that `+` operation is legal in the first place:

```
Dim totalValue As Object
totalValue = rd.Item("total")
If totalValue <> DBNull.Value Then
    ubah = "Update from cabang set total ='" & totalValue + 1 &
            "' where id='" & Mid(ComboBox1.Text, 1, 1) & "'"
Else
    'total is NULL. what now?
End If
```

Also consider using actual `Parameter` objects to use with your `Command`, instead of concatenating user inputs into your command string - [obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/327/): that makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection, and it's a legit bug and a performance issue, not just a hypothetical "security" thing.

Comment: Thanks for the solution